# How to pass data from Node.JS to React build

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Suppose this is my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(9000);
```

And this is the React component which is going to received the data from the server.js:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const DisplayName = (props: any) = {
    return (
              <p>Hi there: {props.match.params.data}</p>
           )
};
```

So how do I pass/post the data to this component from Server.js via URL: i.e. http://example.com/displayName/Phil, http://example.com/displayName/Jake...

Is it possible to do something like these?

```
app.get('/displayName/:data', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

// or

app.post('/displayName/:data', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: You should just have a single route in your backend that serves the `index.html` file, and then handle additional routes with `React` using something like `react-router`. Then you can grab URL parameters, or whatever, in `React` with the tools you have available - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

Comment: When I do npm start the react app (no sever side rendering), the routing works fine. I can pass different data through i.e. /displayName/Ben. I have an Express server that serve a single route for index.html. But when I hit that route /displayName/Ben - its just blank. However, on network it is returning the react static files.

Comment: Yeah, make sure everything is set up properly on both `Express.js` and the `React`/`react-router` end - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

Comment: Thanks, that did work. I created the project from scratch similar to example above. Must be issue in my main project.